# Hypothetical Internet on Phobos

Tags: mars, phobos, optical-communication, internet

If there was a ground base on the surface of Phobos, with current or developing technology, would it be viable to have an internet connection?

Even with optical communication like DSOC, would it be hard to keep the signal since it requires line of sight with Earth?

Where on Phobos would be best to locate the station so it can communicate with Earth? Or would you need satellites to relay...?

Comment: specifically internet? or more generally a communications link?

Comment: what is the difference? i'm interested in the answer to either

Comment: the internet is (afaik) a bunch (?billions) of **inter**connected computer **net**works that store and send data (upon your request) to other devices via the internet protocol suite. Spacecraft are more like the radio in your car where it receives radio waves without having to request them. Combining the internet and spacecraft communications is kind of liking combining the postal/mail service and the internet: the same goal of sending information from A to B, but vastly different methods of doing so that are very minimally related.

Comment: so i mean internet as we are on currently

Comment: The speed of light says your latency will be anywhere from 6 to 45 minutes depending on where Earth and Mars are (you would click to load something and 45 mins later it would start loading) so while it might be possible it doesn't seem practical

Comment: There are several existing questions and answers about interplanetary internet here already, I think this may end up being a duplicate if that's what you want to ask about. *However* trying to set up a communications network *around a small solar system body like Phobos* which aren't so amenable to orbiting communications satellites is quite a challenge and I think that will be an interesting question!

Comment: btw saw your profile & twitter, love it, fyi there is a [space-art](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-art) tag here with 71 questions.

Comment: @uhoh ty! i will check it out :)